# Error while trying to import Google Map related packages in my application

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api

AM trying to use Google map in my android application with the guide lines in this link

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html

i have updated my SDK  and  ADT as well !
I got API key from the Google apis!

but when i importing  the following packages it's rise the error!

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
```

Note  :
When i try to File → Import → Android → Existing Android Code into Workspace. i got an error message like '.**'MainACtivity' is already exist** i suspect this would be the hurdle to jump !

Comment: have you referenced google play services library project?

Comment: have you downloaded the google play services library project?

Comment: @Raghunandan Yes i downloaded ! but when i try to refer the google play services i got an error as i mentioned in NOTE !

Comment: http://tinypic.com/r/2cs7y1e/5. it should look like something in the pic. i don't see a main activity file there.

Comment: This folder doesn't raise any problem but this is the error folder http://s1289.photobucket.com/user/MohanRaj2213/media/error_zpse427356b.png.html and this is how my program looks alike ! http://s1289.photobucket.com/user/MohanRaj2213/media/error1_zpsd441ed4a.png.html

Comment: do i need to add any .jar files ?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html, follow the guide and refer the library project in your android project

Comment: Yes i done with those steps given in develpers site but still i couldn't Referencing the library project it's looks  like http://s1289.photobucket.com/user/MohanRaj2213/media/error2_zpsbe2d48fd.png.html

Comment: that's a borken link. copy the library project to your workspace (folder where your map project is) then import it to workspace and then reference the same. try moving your workspace out of c drive.

Comment: i ll give a try and let u know thanks for ur relay of suggestions !

Comment: You just put it as answer i 'll accept it for sure ! your answers worked fine ! you genius ! :) :)

Comment: i will post the same for clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the steps. From the comments it looks like you have not referenced google play services library project in your map project.

Converting comments to answer for clarity.

1. Download the  Google Play services.

Goto Windows. Goto Android Sdk Manager. Choose Google play services under extras. If not installed install the package.

2.Copy the google-play services_lib library project to your workspace (folder where your project is). The library project can be found under the following path.

```
     <android-sdk-folder>/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib library project .
```

3.Import the library project to your eclipse

Click File > Import, select Android > Existing Android Code into Workspace, and browse the     workspace  import the library project. You can check if it is library project. Right click on the library project. Goto properties. Click Android on the left panel. You will see Is Library checked.

4.Refer to the library project

Right click on your project. got properties. Click Android. Choose Android. Clikc Add browse and add the library project.

More info @

http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

Remember you need to test in a real device

Comment: @LiveITup check this http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html. Its better to check for availability of google play services in your device.

Comment: @LiveITup better to check if google play services apk is installed on device.

Comment: I just want to give a search facility in this application how can i do that ? when i run this app on a real device i could navigate across but i want surf a specific location with a textual location name!

Comment: @LiveITup thats for the device. i would suggest to test it on a real device. If users device does not have google play services apk you can handle that situation.

Comment: I assume you want to zoom in to a location for that you need latitude and longitude of that place and you  can place a marker and zoom your camera to that position.

Comment: @LiveITup check the docs fro more info use google play location service api. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/location

Comment: Yes i can give a pre defined set of balloon markers in my app that's fine, additionally i want to let the users to search the location wherever they wish to !

Answer (score 0):

If those class could not be found then you encountering some problem with the way you reference the `google-play-services` library. You can take a look at this blog post I wrote on this topic and especially the first 3 steps of this guide:

[Google Maps API V2](https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435)

If you have committed the first three steps, and it still didn't helped you, try to move the
this library to another location where it's path would be shorter and then reference it again.

Comment: i ll go through it and let u know the consequences !